# Ornament Symbol for Triplet

Tags: notation, rhythm, ornaments, tuplet

I am writing a piece of music that has a lot of triplets used as ornaments. Is there a symbol like this:

[image: ornament example]

that will be played as as a triplet on the note?

Example: note is G. With symbol over it, it is played as G-F-G (in a triplet). Does this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want  single-pitch triplets, use the [abbreviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation_(music)) notation.  There are examples on that page for triplets.
Here's an example I tripped across on the webz:
[image: abbreviatedtriplets]

The red circles helpfully point you to triplets both written out and abbreviated; they are played the same way.

And no, there is no symbol for groups of 3 notes which are not the same pitch. It should be reasonably obvious why.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is "if you want a triplet, write a triplet".

Ornament signs are not "exact" prescriptions for anything. For contemporary music they not used much, except for trills. Of course they were common in baroque music, but the interpretation was *intentionally* left up to the performer to a very great degree.

The sign in your example usually meant a short trill: not necessarily starting on the written note - it might start on the note above - not necessarily only three notes long, and usually with the final note longer than the others.

There is a similar sign with a vertical line through it, which *does* mean three notes, i.e. the written note, the note below, and the written note repeated, but (1) "the note below" might be interpreted as "a semitone below," i.e. F# not F, and (2) the first two notes are short compared with the third one - it's not a triplet rhythm.

Also, in any period after the Baroque, such ornaments are often interpreted (rightly or wrongly) as being played *before* the beat, with the final note on the beat - which certainly isn't "a triplet".

[image]