# How do I notate for the sostenuto pedal?

Tags: piano, notation, keyboard-pedals, sustain

In another part of the composition mentioned [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/54784/ornament-symbol-for-triplet), I want to use the sostenuto pedal:

[image: sustain pedal]

How can I notate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an American made piano, the notation S.P. is possible (Sostenuto Pedal).

On some Eurpoean pianos, this effect is achieved by a half-pedal technique. One depresses the notes to be held and then depresses the right (damper) pedal halfway down.

Comment: This is an American pedal. Perfect! : )

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the *instrument* has a sostenuto pedal or not - the notation is to show the *effect* required, not the method of playing it.

Comment: You can still write S.P.   A player who finds himself at a piano lacking the Sostenuto pedal will recognise the intention and produce the effect as best he can.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - can't think of an effective way in which to achieve the 'sos' - half pedal on sustain isn't really the same. How would you do it?

Comment: I have no better suggestion than the one @ttw mentions in his reply.

Comment: @Laurence & user19146 the effect is notated by note lengths. the reason you don't see sostenuto markings is because it's not an effect in and of itself (the way the sustain pedal is), it's a technique for achieving an effect already notated on the score. If a chord is written to last, say, 4 beats, but it is unreachable while playing the other notes required and the other notes have short lengths or esp. rests between, then the pianist knows that the sostenuto pedal is necessary to execute the passage properly without muddiness.

Comment: @Tim an assistant is useful for this. Ask him to stand behind you and reach his hands under your arms to reach the keys. From there, when you would normally press the sostenuto pedal, instead swing your head back to bop him on the nose indicating he should hold down the keys you're currently holding. Bop him again to release.

Answer (score 4):

The symbol for the sostenuto pedal is "*Sost. Ped.*".

The "*S*" should be aligned directly below the first moment that it is applied (usually just after the note it is acting on is played, and obviously not before it has finished).
Its extent should be marked with a horizontal line, and its release should be shown by terminating the horizontal line with a short vertical upward line.

[image: example of sostenuto pedal marking]

---

**NB:** Using "*S.P.*" is not a good idea because it could easily be misunderstood as standing for sustain pedal.